# Unit Testing IHttpActionResult Controller - Testing for 200 OK fails

Tags: c#, unit-testing

This is probably a fairly simple question but I'll admit, I'm stuck.

I have a controller that is returning `IHttpActionResult` and I need to write unit tests for this.

Here's the controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetPerson(int id) {

    Person person = repository.Get(id);

    if (person == null) {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

    return Ok(new {
        User = person
    });

}
```

Here's the unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetReturnsValidPerson() {

    var userController = new UserController();

    IHttpActionResult actionResult = userController.GetPerson(1);

    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actionResult, typeof(OkResult));

}
```

And here's the error from the test:

> Assert.IsInstanceOfType failed. Expected
>   type:System.Web.Http.Results.OkResult Actual type:
>   System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult1[<>f__AnonymousType11[DataAccess.BO.Person]]

What exactly is going on here?  The return from the controller is an HTTP 200 Ok response.  Why is this expecting `OkNegotiatedContentResult`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the Asp.Net documentation, the result of an IHttpActionResult is `OkNegotiatedContentResult`. Your Assert comparison should check for that.

[Unit Testing Controllers in Asp.Net](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api)

> Action returns 200 (OK) with a response body
>
> The Get method calls Ok(product) if the product is found. In the unit
>   test, make sure the return type is OkNegotiatedContentResult and the
>   returned product has the right ID.

Comment: I did check the docs and a lot of blogs before I asked, because it seems fairly simple.  Should this not work then?  `Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actionResult, typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<OkResult>));`?  I am still getting a failure due to the types not matching.

Comment: Did you set the return type of this line `IHttpActionResult actionResult = userController.GetPerson(1);` to `OkNegotiatedContentResult`? Although this type of test is redundant. It's best to test for null return and that object that is returned

Comment: I did, I have to cast it and the cast fails.  `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`1[DataAccess.BO.Person]]' to type 'System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult`1[System.Web.Http.Results.OkResult]'.`   I changed the line to `var actionResult = (OkNegotiatedContentResult<OkResult>)userController.GetPerson(1);`.  I think I'm going to just test for the actual result of the object and not the HTTP status code.  Sorry if this is stupid, I'm new to this sort of test with Web API.

Comment: I see what the issue is here.  Due to having to include a root node in the returned JSON, I'm now returning an anonymous type which is causing the casting problems.  For example, the return from the controller is now `return Json(new { User = person });`, simply to give the JSON a root name of `User`.  I have no idea how to cast this to a `OkNegotiatedContentResult<>` which wants a type.